# How to create a .NET web service to insert data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, json, sql-server-2008

I am finding it difficult to implement a .NET web service to insert data in my database created in SQL Server 2008 . I am stuck after implementing the following code :

```
namespace DataService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]

    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld(String entity)
        {
            String firstName = "";
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(
                @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" + 
                @"Initial Catalog=student;User ID=sa;Password=123");
            try
            {
                myConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
                myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
                myCommand.CommandText = "insert into stud values " +
                    "stud_name = '" + firstName + "'";

                SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

                //while
                if (myReader.Read())
                {
                    firstName = myReader["stud_name"].ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            { 
                myConnection.Close();
            }

            return firstName;
        }
    }
}
```

Here entity is the JSONArray i get in the form:

```
[{"key0":"john","key2":"ann","key1":"joe"}]
```

I need to insert each value for eg "john" in the database table.

Comment: Whats your exception? Does your aspnet Worker have all required privilegues to actually access the db? Also you are executing a reader, why not execute a non query. Also, wrap that connection in a using.

Comment: Yeah there's many things that could be happening here.  Debug it and find out what the exception is.  It's probably as @UrbanEsc said that you either have invalid permissions as a service to access the DB, or you could be exhausting the DB connection pool by not Dispose()-ing the connections to free them in the pool faster.

Comment: I am getting an exception for the insert query . I don't knw how to execute a non query . Can u tell me how to do that ? Btw , I have the access privileges for the database in SQL Server . I am working on localhost. The insertion part is giving me a problem

Comment: You should be serializing the data you receive with something like `Newtonsoft.Json`

Comment: @Nico : what is Newtonsoft.Json ? How can I use it ? What will happen if I serialize the JSONArray ?

Comment: @Parth_90: What specifically is your exception?

Comment: @Parth_90 You'll get C#.NET objects you can work with. http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: The question title is missleading; its a SQLCommand insertion problem, not a JSON or a webservices issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parth_90:

First, if you are getting a JSONArray from the client side, I suggest you Deserialize it first in a List

```
JavascripSerializer js = new JavascriptSerializer<List<sring>>();
List<string> recordsToInsert= js.Deserialize(entity);
```

Then  you can insert every record in the table by either looping through them and enclosing everything in a Transaction.

```
foreach(name in recordsToInsert)
{
 //perform the table insert here... 
 //Your SQL code seems correct to me. 
}
```

Improvement: [Enclose the insert statements in a SQLTransaction.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.aspx)

**EDIT**: Adding some code demonstrating how to Deserialize the example JSON string provided in the question:

```
private static void DoSerializationTest()
    {
        string entity="{\"key0\":\"john\",\"key2\":\"ann\",\"key1\":\"joe\"}";
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        Dictionary<string,string> result= js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,string>>(entity);
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value: "+item.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Key :"+item.Key);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where should I write the serializer code , should I write it in my Android app ?

Comment: @Parth_90: No, the JavascriptSerializer is part of the .NET Framework, you don't need to write it. See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: After serializing what will be my output ? I am new to all this in .NET please can u help give me some more idea regarding the code ?

Comment: @Parth_90: The C# code is there also, simply click on the tabs with the C# name on them to see the examples in C#.

Comment: After serializing what will be my output ? I am new to all this in .NET please can u help give me some more idea regarding the code ?

Comment: @Parth_90: See my updated answer. I included a sample test case. That should get you going.

Comment: @Icarus let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3015/discussion-between-parth-90-and-icarus)

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your command with ExecuteNonQuery(); ExecuteReader is for when you execute a select to get data from the database.

```
  SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
                    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
                    myCommand.CommandText = "insert into stud values " +
                        "stud_name = '" + firstName + "'";
     if(myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
     {
         //The command executed with affected rows > 0, OK.
     }
     else
     {
         //No rows affected by the execution. Error management.
     }
```